# Generate new empty Clojure packages and files to existing leiningen projects

Tags: clojure, code-generation, leiningen

I have an existing leiningen project, I was wondering if there is anyway leiningen will allow me to automatically generate empty Clojure files or packages without me doing it manually.

For example when you create a new project in leiningen it will automatically generate the project package with core.clj inside it, is there any way to do this for existing projects that will automatically generate the namespace code inside the file?

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leiningen seems not to yet have a plugin for this, Leiningen is generally unaware of any namespaces other than the main and the :aot classes so there has yet to be a significant demand for a new namespace leiningen task.

you can of course [write your own](http://nakkaya.com/2010/02/25/writing-leiningen-plugins-101/)

Comment: Thanks, I may have to write my own if I get time.